# Why NSManagedObjectContext returns null when extending it?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to extend `NSManagedObjectContext` and instantiate an object from it as follows:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    func persist(block: @escaping ()->Void) {
        perform {
            block()

            do {
                try self.save()
            } catch {
                self.rollback()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the controller:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
func saveFamilyMember(withName name: String) {
    guard let moc = managedObjectContext
        else { return }

    moc.persist {
        let familyMember = FamilyMember(context: moc)
        familyMember.name = name
        print("xxxxxxxx")
    }
}
```

When I print line before `guard let moc` it prints it but not after. It doesn't return any error as it is safely unwrapped but doesn't function.

Comment: Where do you assign a value to the `managedObjectContext` variable?

Comment: @TomHarrington I didn't assign a value to it. What value I have to assign to make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
```

But as you mention in a comment, you never assign a value. As a result it's nil. You're not safely unwrapping it-- your `guard` check is failing so you're never getting past it to the `persist` call. There's nothing to unwrap, but the `guard` means that you don't crash.

Creating a managed object context depends on how your app is set up and on where/when this code needs to execute. In recent versions of iOS you usually use `NSPersistentContainer` to set up Core Data. It has a `viewContext` attribute that's useful for UI related code or it can create background contexts for server communication or other background work. You probably want one of those, but which one depends on where/when you call this code.

[You can create managed object contexts by other means but it's unusual to need that these days. You **cannot** simply initialize one as something like `NSManagedObjectContext()`.]